# HTML Anchor tags in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I just started learning wordpress. managed to make my first custom theme. but there is a problem.. In my sidebar.php there is a list menu in the form of categories. Like Category 1, Category 2 etc.
I want that when i click on category 1, it should take me to category.php but unfortunately, it gives me that file doesn't exists even though it does. I have made that theme active. 
here's my code

```
<li><a href="category.php">Category one</a></li>
```

What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: If category.php is in the "root" of your site, you can try to use this: <li><a href="/category.php">Category one</a></li>

Comment: my directory is C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is in your theme's directory, try this instead:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/category.php">Category one</a></li>
```

Comment: <li><a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/category.php">Category one</a></li>                                                                 This Worked!! But nnow it is giving me Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()... And thank you